# Android, How to add a tab and ensure the new Fragment uses the main Activities Layout?

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

My app is a grade calculator.

What I want to do is have a page that displays a table that users can input their grades into for a specific course. If the user wishes to add another course they should be able to add a new tab which will display an empty table for them to fill in.

Can someone please let me know if there are any tutorials to get me started.

As of now my app has an Activity called "Courses" which stores all the table input in an SQLite database. So my app is functioning perfectly but the user can only store data for one course.

I have watched this one http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2UZDrYNsX4 but I am confused about how to make the new fragment's layout match the " Courses' " layout. This tutorial has each Fragment using a brand new blank layout.

Comment: I think you may be getting confused WRT layouts. An `Activity` has it's own layout and if it uses `Fragments` the `Activity` layout will have some sort of 'container' (usually based on a `FrameLayout`) in which the `Fragments` are placed. The `Fragments` have their own layout files and it's possible to replace the contents of the `Activity's` container with any type of `Fragment` and it's possible to create multiple instances of the same `Fragment` using the same layout but with different data content. In short, use a simple `Activity` layout and let your `Fragments` handle their own layouts.

Comment: Do you know of any good tutorials that teach you the basics of how to implement multiple instances of one fragment?